# breaking a nested loop

Tags: c#, loops, break

I have a nested loop which is checking if any `Currency` of `Wallet[]` matches any `Currency` in `Currency[] UtilityTokens`.
Upon determining that indeed one of the wallets contains a utility token, I want to break my nested loop as soon as possible to move on.

My current code is the following:

```
bool walletContainsUtilityToken = false;
for(int i = 0; i < Wallets.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (Currency ut in ExchangeFunctions.UtilityTokens)
    {
        if (Wallets[i].Currency.Equals(ut))
        {
            walletContainsUtilityToken = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (walletContainsUtilityToken)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Is this the apropriate way to break nested loops?
Is there a different, more efficient way of doing things?

Comment: Nothing that `return` can't do.  WalletContainsUtilityToken() is a good method name.

Comment: yes, thats what I ended up with after all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get this down to a one-liner, and it **will** do the early exit you want:

```
bool walletContainsUtilityToken = Wallets.Any(w => ExchangeFunctions.UtilityTokens.Any( ut => ut == w.Currency));
```

This one might be easier to understand (no nesting, only one -shorter- lambda):

```
bool walletContainsUtilityToken = Wallets.Select(w => w.Currency).Intersect(ExchangeFunctions.UtilityTokens).Any();
```

Taking the second option, for clarity I'd actually write it like this:

```
bool walletContainsUtilityToken = Wallets.
    Select(w => w.Currency).
    Intersect(ExchangeFunctions.UtilityTokens).
    Any();
```

If you *really* want to continue using the full loop, I'd add a check to the loop conditions like so:

```
bool walletContainsUtilityToken = false;
for(int i = 0; i < Wallets.Length && !walletContainsUtilityToken; i++)
{
    foreach (Currency ut in ExchangeFunctions.UtilityTokens)
    {
        if (Wallets[i].Currency.Equals(ut))
        {
            walletContainsUtilityToken = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if these lists are large you could significantly improve performance by pre-arranging them into data structures for faster lookup (ie: a Dictionary, or even something that would support a binary search). But this is only a win if the lists are large enough.

Comment: thank you very much sir! I did not know, multiple loop permissions were possible. I prefer the loop due to faster lookup times (at least in previous bnchmarks I did)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `goto`.

example:

```
            int val = 2;

            for(int i = 0; i <4;i++)    
            {
                for (int j =0;j<4; j++)
                {
                    if (val == i)
                        goto LoopsFinished;
                }

            }

            LoopsFinished:
                val = 0;
```

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO. There are far better options available.

Comment: Come on. I don't think C# goto is bad. The only reason is goto got lot of anti fanbase for the chaos it created in some other programming languages. :) :)

Comment: It creates chaos in any language because its fundamental nature is the same in any programming language. While there are edge cases where it's *necessary*, this is absolutely not one of them.

Comment: I think C# has decent restrictions on using goto.

Comment: The documentation clearly says we cannot even transfer control outside fucntion..... If a label with the given name doesn't exist in the current function member, or if the goto statement is not within the scope of the label, a compile-time error occurs. That is, you can't use the goto statement to transfer control out of the current function member or into any nested scope, for example, a try block.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements#the-goto-statement

Comment: Any structured programming language has that restriction. You can still create plenty of chaos in any of them within those limits. If you can do something without `goto`, don't use `goto`. OP already had something that was perfectly fine, and better than using `goto`.

Comment: Just trying to understand.... Is there any other purpose the language is still maintaining this keyword other than jump out of loops..

Comment: There are some things that you *can't* express within the language. Here's an example: I once had a `for` loop with a `try/catch` inside of it, but entering the `try/catch` every iteration was killing performance. So I switched it. I put the `for` loop within the `try`, and when it caught an exception, it handled it, used `goto` to go back and re-enter the `try/catch`, and resume the loop within it from where it left off. It enters the `try/catch` only (0..1)+E times, where E is the number of exceptions thrown, vs. N times where N is the number of iterations. (0..1)+E will never exceed N.

Comment: A `goto` was necessary because the program structure I needed couldn't be represented in the language otherwise. And I ***commented the heck out of what it was doing*** so that it could be maintained properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine, if you want a one-liner here is a Linq alternative.

```cs
bool walletContainsUtilityToken = Wallets.Any(w => ExchangeFunctions.UtilityTokens.Any(ut => w.Currency.Equals(ut)));
```